# Warning about remaining space on Windows RE Tools partition in Windows 10 - What to do?

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

I just installed Windows 10, and I noticed that Windows also created a 450MB partition called Windows RE tools (Recovery environment). Which is fine by me, but I also get constant warnings from Windows that I'm about to run out of space on the disk.

From what I've found online, there is no way to suppress these messages for a specific drive, only globally - which I don't want to do. But I figured if I extended the size so that the remaining space is over the threshold of the warning (200 MB IIRC), the warnings should stop.

Unfortunately, Disk Management only gives me the option to shrink the partition, not resize it, although I have plenty of unallocated space on the drive (not part of any partition, meant for a future Linux install).

Here is my disk management screenshot

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas how to change the partition size? Or alternatively, how to get rid of the space warning for this specific drive?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here is a free partition software](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) Be sure to back up all your data to an external drive before using this, also disconnect any usb hard drives and Internal hard drives that are Not going to be re-sized.

Comment: Low disk space is hard coded for individual drives but [can be turned off for all drives](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555622)

Comment: When using partition software what you want to do is take some space from that unallocated partition to the left and add it to the RE partition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

I know how to turn of the warning for all drives, but that seems a bit overkill and potentially dangerous.

Comment: Ok, that did it. Thanks for the link. I guess I expected a bit too much from Windows ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are scores of tools around such as "Partition Magic", "Partition Master" and "gPart".  Just google for it.  Some are even free.

I Use "Partition Magic", and I am not associated with them.

**EDIT**

I had reason to use it again on WIndows 10, and it would not resize the partition.  But the latest version of **Parttion Wizard** did the trick.

Comment: Partition magic is outdated software, I do not recommend using it in W10.